# Height of custom cell after init in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a table with custom cell. These cells have different heights, and I know how to calculate the height. The problem is that the **heightForRowAtIndexPath** method is called before  of method **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, so I can not pass the CGFloat of return.

Is there a way to invoke this method after?

Thanks a lot

EDIT

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCellFavorites *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[CustomCellFavorites alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.topSuperiore = self;

}

//textviews

NSString *string01 = ((Traduzioni *)[self.arrayTraduzioni objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).testoOriginale;
NSString *string02 = ((Traduzioni *)[self.arrayTraduzioni objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).testoTradotto;

[cell loadItem:string01 :string02];

return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
CustomCellFavorites *cell = (CustomCellFavorites*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell.heightCell;

}
```

custom cell method

```
-(void)loadItem:(NSString *)text01:(NSString *)text02 {
textView01.text = text01;
CGRect rect = textView01.frame;
rect.size.height = textView01.contentSize.height;
textView01.frame = rect;
[tv01Bg setFrame:CGRectMake(32, 0, 288, (textView01.contentSize.height)+20)];
textView02.text = text02;

CGRect rect2 = textView02.frame;
rect2.size.height = textView02.contentSize.height;
textView02.frame = rect2;
[tv02Bg setFrame:CGRectMake(0, (textView01.contentSize.height)+20, 320, (textView02.contentSize.height)+20)];
heightCell = (rect2.origin.y)+(rect2.size.height)+15.5;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to invoke this method after. The way I have handled this is to basically get the actual row & depending on the type of row, decide the height. Some brief code follows -

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSObject *res     = [self.resultSet objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    if([res isKindOfClass:[someX class]])
        return 110;
    else if([res isKindOfClass:[someY class]])
        return 120;
    else if([res isKindOfClass:[someZ class]])
        return 230;
    else
        return 175.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the height can varied 100% and I can't create all the various possibilities.

Comment: can you tell something more about the type of data you are handling? & the reason you need so much variation in height?

Comment: Of course, I have two TextView in the cell, they vary based on what the user wrote. The sum of the heights and spaces are included in this heightCell Float ` - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 CustomCellFavorites *cell = (CustomCellFavorites*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 return cell.heightCell;
 
}`in the custom cell `heightCell = (rect2.origin.y)+(rect2.size.height)+15.5;`

Comment: then if you knew how many textViews are present then couldn't you figure out the total height then ? or couldn't you use `cellID` to figure out the type of cell & then custom code the height?

Comment: It could actually be an idea:) could you tell me more about how you would use the cell id?

Comment: since you are using custom cells, you know exactly how much height each type of cell ought to be. so if you extract the cellID in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` then based on that decide the height.

Comment: Ok, i understand. Anyway  I edit the post to understand better.